# How to append all Google spreadsheets from a google folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a master Google Sheet and a google folder containing 5-6 sheets.

How to append all those 5-6 sheets into the master sheet with GAS? (They are all with same headers.), so that I can automate this action by changing the Folder ID.

I found the below which could identify all sheets in the folder but no know the next steps. Please help.

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//change the folder ID below to reflect your folder's ID (look in the URL when you're in your folder)
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***ID***");
var contents = folder.getFiles();

var cnt = 0;
var file;

while (contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();
    cnt++;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can get the data using `SpreadsheetApp` and append the values using `getRange().setValues()`.*

#### Code example:

This is made a little generically as I do not know the structure of your folder/sheets:

```js
function appendData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var tempFile = "";
    var file = files.next();
    // if the file is not a Sheet, skip it
    if (file.getMimeType() != "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      tempFile = { 
        "title": file.getName(), 
        "parents": [ {
          "id": folderId
        }] 
      }; 

      file = Drive.Files.insert(tempFile, file.getBlob(), { "convert": true });
    }
      
    var importSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    // assuming you only want to append the first sheet of each Spreadsheet:
    var range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
    
    // extend the main sheet if you need to:
    try {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + range.getNumRows(), 1);
    }
    catch (e) {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows(), range.getNumRows() + 1);
    }    
    // remove the headers from the data to copy:    
    range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, range.getNumRows() - 1, range.getNumColumns())
    
    // copy the data:
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + 1, 1, range.getNumRows(), range.getNumColumns()).setValues(range.getValues());
    if (tempFile != "") {
      Drive.Files.Delete(file.getId());
  }
}
```

Things this code does:

- Gets the files from the specified folder
- Converts the file to a Spreadsheet file if it's an Excel file
- Uses `SpreadsheetApp` to get the Sheet data
- Checks to see if the sheet to import to has enough rows, and adds the needed rows if it doesn't
- Removes the headers from the data to import so it doesn't get duplicated
- Copies in the data
- Deletes the temp file if the file was an Excel file

Make sure to enable the Advanced Drive Service from the `Resources > Advanced Google services...` menu item.

#### References:

- [Class `SpreadsheetApp` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class `Sheet` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class `Range` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thanks for your help and instructions. However, could you also help how to solve this error:
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID 10000lmeL1x93mzQjyoPkLNo6J7K00000. (line 8, file "MasterSheet")
The Access right is "Everyone can edit"

Comment: This is likely because there are other files in the folder than Spreadsheet files. I updated the code to skip these files.

Comment: Appreciated. I am trying to see if I have doing anything wrong since no response we I run it. Will feedback to you soon.

Comment: Updated, try this code again now. I missed the second `files.next()` call so it was skipping twice.

Comment: There are no error but no response still. Appreciated if there is a fix since I could not find a mistake by myself.

Comment: Did you update to the latest answer I posted? If so, please can you share a screenshot of your Drive folder structure and a sanitised copy of your master sheet?

Comment: I just created a testing folder and set it as everyone with the link can edit.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UQ5J3xdNnqyHvC-CJ1vAu5YPSxq9Sya9

And your script started with this

`function appendData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UQ5J3xdNnqyHvC-CJ1vAu5YPSxq9Sya9");
  var files = folder.getFiles();`

Comment: I find root cause is that this script is only applicable to google sheets but not excel files, which mean when a folder contains both Google sheets and Excel files, it can only append the google files. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work on Excel files, Sheets and Excel files are not the same thing. You would need to convert your Excel file to a Sheet before appending using the Advanced Drive Service. I've updated my code to reflect this change.